# list single attribute of single post then I'll repeat in loop

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I am writing a very simple react app that will list the posts in my WordPress site. 
1) Fetch the posts and set them to a state variable.
2) Successfully access the posts from `render()`.
3) Loop through the posts rendering the title and other information about each post.

1 and 2 are finished, so now I need to do 3.  When I try to print the title of a post it tells me that it `cannot access 'title' of undefined.` . I know what you are thinking and I am able to print the post if I write a loop that prints out every key of the post (loop commented out), but if I try to print out the value of just one key I get an error saying the post is undefined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            posts: []
        };
    }


    componentWillMount() {
      const theUrl = "http://localhost:8888/test-site/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
      fetch(theUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({
          posts: response,
        })
      )
    }


    render() {
      let post = this.state.posts[0];

      // for (var key in post) {
      //   console.log(key + ': ' + post[key]);
      // }

      let title = post['title'].rendered;

      let stringbuilder = '';

      try {
        stringbuilder +=  title + ', ';
    } catch {}


        return (
            <div>
              <h1>React Widget</h1>
              {stringbuilder}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Widget.propTypes = {
  wpObject: PropTypes.object
};
```

This question is probably easy for some of the more advanced react devs, but how can I print just the `title` attribute of `post`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that React is trying to render the posts before the asynchronous fetch returns a result and updates the state.

In your render, just check if `posts` has more than 0 values:

```javascript
//...
    render() {
      const { posts } = this.state;

      if (posts && posts.length) {
        let post = posts[0];

        // for (var key in post) {
        //   console.log(key + ': ' + post[key]);
        // }

        let title = post['title'].rendered;

        let stringbuilder = '';

        try {
          stringbuilder +=  title + ', ';
        } catch {}


        return (
          <div>
            <h1>React Widget</h1>
            {stringbuilder}
          </div>
        );
      }

      // Return null while loading
      // Or, return useful info like <p>Loading Posts...</p>
      return null;
    } 
//...
```

Also, you should use `componentDidMount` as `componentWillMount` [has been deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).